# Typesafe Activator, how does one get it to build a project successfully?

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

What is the trick of getting typesafe activator to build one of the projects on its menu of tutorials / demos?

Every month or so I download the latest version of typesafe-activator (most recently 1.3.6, 476 MB).  Previously I have been using linux mint, but now I have a nice clean install of debian 8.  I do 'activator ui' thing and then pick out a scala web project.  This time I chose 'play slick angular test' and tried to build and run it.  It failed.  As far as I can recall, I have never had a success with any of these things.  This time it failed with 'Could not load build configuration.'  Being an optimist, I simply tried to build it again.  Mirabile dictu, it appeared to make more progress, the second time, but failed with "[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-fork-run-plugin;2.3.1: not found ..."

OK, so one project fails.  I try another one, "slick sortable ..." It builds a while and then comes to a stop waiting for sbt to restart and it sure looks like it is dead.

If this stuff generally works,  why do I have such problems?  Are there hidden pre-requisites for these projects?  Is 4GB of memory not enough?
This happens to me time and again, several times per year, for I do not know how many years.

I can tell from 280+ questions on typesafe activator here that others get more progress before stuff breaks. Please someone smarten me up.  TIA.

Comment: Found the fix for this issue Here is the link from github on the same issue: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1036 There is a "fix" for this coming. But Activator 1.3.x does not support Play less than version 2.3.8.